# With valid SPF, DKIM, and DMAR, Office 365 email still goes to junk mail and got Authentication-Results-Original: spf=none

Tags: spf, dkim

My goal is to be able to send email from my website using smtp.office365.com and the emails will go into inbox instead of junk mail. But so far, I have not  succeed.

- If the receipt is gmail, the emails will go to inbox fine.
- But for Microsoft Office 365 receipts, the emails always go to junk mail.

The frustrating part is that SPF, DKIM, DMARC all pass. Well, I should say, 4 out 6 check points pass. Here is the extremely confusing part. Even for the gmail receipts, the emails did go to inbox, I still observe this same 4 out 6 pass, 2 fail situation.

I checked the email header. It seems there are 6 rounds of verification. What is confusing is the at the earlier checkpoints, my spf dkim dmarc are all pass. But then in the later 2 parts of the email header, SPF is none. I summarized the 6 check points as below. I also pasted the complete header here. I have been up to my eyeballs on this, reading numerous articles on the internet but couldn't figure how to make the last 2 check points as pass. My email still go to junk mail folder. Someone please shed some light on this dark tunnel. I don't see any hope right now. :(

Here is how I set my SPF

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:mywebsite ip4 ip6:mywebsite ip6 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

Here is how I set DKIM

```
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=my pubic key
```

Here is how I set DMARC

```
v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:email@mydomain.com
```

The 6 check points from the email header

1. ARC-Authentication-Results: spf=pass dkim=pass dmarc=pass
2. Authentication-Results: spf=pass dkim=pass dmarc=pass
3. Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of mydomain.com
   designates 40.107.243.43 as permitted sender)
4. ARC-Authentication-Results: spf=pass dkim=pass dmarc=pass
5. Authentication-Results-Original: spf=none (sender IP is )
6. Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: mydomain.com does not designate
   permitted sender hosts)

---

complete email header

---

```
 ARC-Authentication-Results: i=2; mx.microsoft.com 1; spf=pass (sender ip is
 40.107.243.43) smtp.rcpttodomain=hotmail.com smtp.mailfrom=mydomain.com;
 dmarc=pass (p=reject sp=reject pct=100) action=none
 header.from=mydomain.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
 header.d=netorgft3858956.onmicrosoft.com; arc=pass (0 oda=1 ltdi=1
 spf=[1,1,smtp.mailfrom=mydomain.com] dkim=[1,1,header.d=mydomain.com]
 dmarc=[1,1,header.from=mydomain.com])

 Received: from SN1NAM01FT009.eop-nam01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.152.64.52) by SN1NAM01HT139.eop-nam01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.152.65.197) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.2900.18; Sun, 12 Apr
 2020 21:03:41 +0000

 Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 40.107.243.43)
 smtp.mailfrom=mydomain.com; hotmail.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
 header.d=NETORGFT3858956.onmicrosoft.com;hotmail.com; dmarc=pass action=none
 header.from=mydomain.com;compauth=pass reason=100

 Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of mydomain.com
 designates 40.107.243.43 as permitted sender)
 receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=40.107.243.43;
 helo=NAM12-DM6-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com;
 Received: from NAM12-DM6-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (40.107.243.43)
 by SN1NAM01FT009.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.65.54) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.2900.18 via Frontend Transport; Sun, 12 Apr 2020 21:03:40 +0000
 X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker:
 OriginalChecksum:F5F3FFF61F9E4477F1F3B30CB8587502FF2B1026E8AEF7FE80FDAB59218A2BAC;UpperCasedChecksum:903EAF958FCDDD1FA09C1B9ED806AB00E5149FBB754F6D3EA04FE9A6050CB98A;SizeAsReceived:5869;Count:43
 ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; s=arcselector9901; d=microsoft.com; cv=none;
 b=K5/XSgZYEECmZI+WSF5mybBGLukGhosRKwLxCkiFBJ6MsQbT2fEGkP3v47QHGdc3q9yG1cTw/dDFjlAbWYAeQC7BfHf/SVcv20KAjzU2GOQ3HOgAe14xvTR90TI468OYi+EPiOLWiZSn8ex02O+G6zy5TNYhxOqCky895GUvYShvjYkCz7y5Lk9602y4GxWI2s/JO1KDysHEozDRObQvHgWMClsbQ3EY5LSq7+DfssEt4yzXk1bWX30heCCoZzv0qpYLCa+e74KRUpZDiS8ApCX+faR9xTnkNvInsQO2VO0quKh1mZ8zcbfgLCZD5eV2qkVnQlFxg8q+28zUW2xcJg==

 ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=microsoft.com;
 s=arcselector9901;
 h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck;
 bh=FEoOtS0LShClyJqsdDLafGX7ABa4mJpS7VUSDOhsAvo=;
 b=T0i/lwvdY/00TTdld3Gn+1tkHxnafSdKNXDRKE2hMx+J2tvHHdmuFeYJ56Nb6Li81Muz0RC2AV9nmNwf/dsKpiBwDMk3rNOFQn/ybgJqm0+Rx760XkoThbZevq+v80aZoIoWiuv2uwT/FlTaSomyI2jYVeRUL9tfsBlEK/kcqZUIpK+Svs2d0rWXAg1dIec5Tz4wOrTiEuoKfvRfmgz3p1c+aUVYCPCvtr5xyFNl77mnKV1ZACfYd7DqKOoi/vBl/+RP1YGRiDYq0GI7spaXEXpRfZgFo/EgGKffS3IKF0cDFJBnKZbjXIZQ+IGRTY0BR/OfBh4OEAjEhCkOqg6Z6w==

 ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.microsoft.com 1; spf=pass
 smtp.mailfrom=mydomain.com; dmarc=pass action=none
 header.from=mydomain.com; dkim=pass header.d=mydomain.com; arc=none
 DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=NETORGFT3858956.onmicrosoft.com;
 s=selector2-NETORGFT3858956-onmicrosoft-com;
 h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck;
 bh=FEoOtS0LShClyJqsdDLafGX7ABa4mJpS7VUSDOhsAvo=;
 b=KMx/4rF+7pLmgSR+rCypM8GlcgV3o7Bsoma9Vaayo2n5/qugm7VRY8Z0stSMm0D2nJPgMUz8Eb7CSck1djF2EN14a5ZHiej6eRC9Z3VFNVHiB8NoC9yZLtGxV4uPY9jh64l4m1bMwlBsQvR7cNggj99fTs8oAis973srfpab5c0=

 Authentication-Results-Original: spf=none (sender IP is )
 smtp.mailfrom=email@mydomain.com; 
 Received: from BL0PR05MB4706.namprd05.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:58::28)
 by BL0PR05MB4594.namprd05.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:54::17) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.2921.20; Sun, 12 Apr
 2020 21:03:38 +0000
 Received: from BL0PR05MB4706.namprd05.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::545c:d733:40dc:8226]) by BL0PR05MB4706.namprd05.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::545c:d733:40dc:8226%4]) with mapi id 15.20.2921.022; Sun, 12 Apr 2020
 21:03:38 +0000
 Date: Sun, 12 Apr 2020 17:03:37 -0400
 Return-Path: email@mydomain.com

 To: receiver@hotmail.com
 From: My Website <email@mydomain.com>
 Subject: Replacement login information for receiver@hotmail.com at my website
 Message-ID: <c3918ee3f37544680e96b9eeecb64713@www.mydomain.com>
 X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
 X-ClientProxiedBy: MN2PR15CA0046.namprd15.prod.outlook.com
 (2603:10b6:208:237::15) To BL0PR05MB4706.namprd05.prod.outlook.com
 (2603:10b6:208:58::28)
 X-MS-Exchange-MessageSentRepresentingType: 1
 Received: from www.mydomain.com (2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fe9d:f920) by MN2PR15CA0046.namprd15.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:237::15) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.2900.17 via Frontend Transport; Sun, 12 Apr 2020 21:03:37 +0000
 X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
 X-Originating-IP: [2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fe9d:f920]
 X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
 X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 9517a6ea-47b9-4e09-3f93-08d7df24fa5b
 X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: BL0PR05MB4594:|SN1NAM01HT139:
 X-Microsoft-Antispam-PRVS:
 <BL0PR05MB45941EF0A6C2FD3D650922EAA7DC0@BL0PR05MB4594.namprd05.prod.outlook.com>
 X-MS-Oob-TLC-OOBClassifiers: OLM:8273;
 X-Forefront-PRVS: 0371762FE7
 X-Forefront-Antispam-Report-Untrusted:
 CIP:255.255.255.255;CTRY:;LANG:en;SCL:1;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;H:BL0PR05MB4706.namprd05.prod.outlook.com;PTR:;CAT:NONE;SFTY:;SFS:(10009020)(346002)(366004)(39830400003)(396003)(376002)(136003)(47550400004)(7696005)(508600001)(45080400002)(6916009)(108616005)(2906002)(24736004)(52116002)(186003)(16526019)(52230400001)(316002)(966005)(66556008)(8676002)(86362001)(5660300002)(4744005)(8936002)(66574012)(81156014)(55016002)(66946007)(66476007)(6770600001)(47956004)(1531001)(15302535012);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101;

 Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: mydomain.com does not designate
 permitted sender hosts)
 X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck: 1
 X-Microsoft-Antispam-Untrusted: BCL:0;
 X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info-Original:
 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
 X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData:
 6eQE7H/QYoGc6mz98WrbhfPc53bFbojvNBElQo8cEmlwpdRX/WMJ31LjxbaKUijAqrxDahXPUInIRmh4QMEIvesHL2Aq8X8tXlfHo1oi5HXnwmjaeoafUd7CCWg3AkWtECbwetJ2pa/m8WcFpNOB/IdC8eXeDlCAb1/UolfQ78iUYASA5rYOM2RTLFBc+9sQ
 X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: BL0PR05MB4594
 X-IncomingHeaderCount: 43
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 12 Apr 2020 21:03:40.8315
 (UTC)
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
 9517a6ea-47b9-4e09-3f93-08d7df24fa5b
 X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
 X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
 X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStripped:
 SN1NAM01FT009.eop-nam01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersPromoted:
 SN1NAM01FT009.eop-nam01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
 CIP:40.107.243.43;CTRY:US;LANG:en;SCL:0;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;H:NAM12-DM6-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com;PTR:mail-dm6nam12on2043.outbound.protection.outlook.com;CAT:NONE;SFTY:;SFS:;DIR:INB;SFP:;
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
 SN1NAM01FT009.eop-nam01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
 X-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 4/12/2020 9:03:10 PM
 X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id-Prvs:
 2521d295-637b-47a2-0f56-08d7df24f8b0
 X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true
 X-Sender-IP: 40.107.243.43
 X-SID-PRA: EMAIL@MYDOMAIN.COM
 X-SID-Result: PASS
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
 X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
 X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
 X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 12 Apr 2020 21:03:40.7546
 (UTC)
 X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 9517a6ea-47b9-4e09-3f93-08d7df24fa5b
 X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
 X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
 X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg:
 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: SN1NAM01HT139
 X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:00.7701309
 X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.2900.012
 X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
 abwl:1;rwl:0;ucf:0;jmr:0;ex:1;auth:1;dest:I;OFR:SenderInAddressBook;ENG:(5062000262)(9000001)(9030002)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900115)(4920090)(6375004)(4950130)(560107);
 X-Message-Info:
 5vMbyqxGkdfWvkml9Q14yRenf/nn4DUZ1duaesO4N0V9KAzWFGb/0BEgLbBV4yK2AFu9Bv5hSLRDpI2G6KD7DEyIxqap640xF4cqVg3VRTS5hgAUEHbr1PYMbZtjeydAJCae3q8EWtdzXF/P72K34sxBNfK+visP4x13lyRSvhPI92cUC7/SIDmYD12O8OXG5kfrm6E/B+SfQdkYpu+5GA==
 X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0tMQ==
 X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
 =?utf-8?B?U0pzRC9lK3oyYzJ5QkVwUGd4KzgwUUFxdkRoQ1VNOVRGUnA4M05LRE9kREQ1?=
 =?utf-8?B?bWYzWThkTFJnWllMNWwvU1JhcHBNdHg2UVpEY1ljSzE3T05KZm9WcThHZ2VU?=
 =?utf-8?B?a2lNQUhpdFJhU2pjTlpCdzdOSlpxaHd3M25haVN4eUw3NGZUdG1RZ0ErczdB?=
 =?utf-8?B?Nnhhdy9OaGpmQnN0TW1kZmRwZFYrbEtvcmlXM3pwUkwwMk8rSGxFTWVEL2lO?=
 =?utf-8?B?T2ZETEg1TFZwcFViblNNcXk4SmRab3RDc21vY3Z0cHhZS0pScFN1L3U5UC9H?=
 =?utf-8?B?a1AxVTlJeHpUYTdEQ2U2OGdQSVltVmVIVzNtYlRYUjBGTzIrZ1pLSjZLQlpx?=
 =?utf-8?B?R0p0QmJFR3NWYWVXQjJ4K2tza2twMVJQeVdVMEFMa0s5SUZFRzdrc3Z1UTVt?=
 =?utf-8?B?Z2xoTnFrTXBsT0ZCMkNLLzg5dDloS29TWVlQOU5WZkljc2VhWTBzaWk1Z0t6?=
 =?utf-8?B?d0FHbndTeGVlNXU4aUw2Z2lOeW1haVl3SVh6NjE4VzBRS0hPWjhqUGxlbUpL?=
 =?utf-8?B?VjVNZDd4ZElKU0VXT05DbjcxTHNheVpkcCtDeXp5aEI0YjlKSTA0bkZ5NFFT?=
 =?utf-8?B?SHZpTC8wbitGOFFsd1F3Sjl0Z0ltZkVJby9jRm9paHQydjhLN2ptdVl3NWh1?=
 =?utf-8?B?UXFWMDZnS1paQU8vZnFvS0xZNEJvYlZzazRueWpuN2JzZGtZS2pLNEJpTy9M?=
 =?utf-8?B?bjZCdEhXTVlQb0xLSjRkYm0yK2xva25JaDBiUXJrUDhISmxSOVhPcGhLb2h5?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZWJZZHIwV3IrWW1sdGhDcFgrRkIzVVZJbFl6N1lFOWd6aDAycVg3M2hteUcw?=
 =?utf-8?B?RXFidGxQaEI2TEwycitkVlJrYllxeXluTEVjKzl0ZWttbVdMNGg4Ry9OM0Zo?=
 =?utf-8?B?R3JzME4rbWE4UVdldEpkM0I5OGluSjV4bFprdXJ4eE50SnFNUElHRWMwVEdR?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZTJhQXl5WjNPT3l2MWIxQlczYlM2c1Vudmxwc0czd0Jua0xtYTVlSENzVTVC?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZDVrWGxQMW1sU1pnSjd2alh5Q0lIMVN1ZDFmazdJMjU3MnJsa21SVVZnOC85?=
 =?utf-8?B?bE5mNjJCeHFKQmVQa1BCS3FuT3c1clFpT3JuVStWQnJFVEFYQ2YzUnhaV2th?=
 =?utf-8?B?Y2NIeEFhdVVTMEVpT1VjMHZVRDZEYm1WREJZU1d5ZFVoNHI2Z3pOS0NnaUlv?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZmhLZ1Z0ZDNnZHFTRTNpNFlQQkhxLyt2WUZYT0lDNDBBWnVkQzNmd0lrZ3Js?=
 =?utf-8?B?cnRZbDJ5Wmd0NUV5TWJ1N0dOenhyNW9vQWU4d0hFTDEvcFpQdzNVU3lFcmNF?=
 =?utf-8?B?TVdvRmEvbTVIeHphUzREWUcxMGQ3RityT3AyNmJEdHJhSFVaQXZCRktCeVFW?=
 =?utf-8?B?OHFwdWovVFlVOHY1ZzM4Z3JLZWhRTU9MSWZtYWg0NSt1SFkvL3VZMnlaOGhN?=
 =?utf-8?B?N3ExSW4rY1N1NTBqUUtDR3RhcmduSnI5NGprMUd1ckN2dmR3aFF1OHRndGZk?=
 =?utf-8?Q?nuoRHc=3D?=
 MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: `Authentication-Results-Original: spf=none` tells me there is something wrong with your SPF record most likely?  I see ip4 and ip6 and mx without values in what you provided.  Should be a TXT record with @ (root) for name.  I know this is old so you've probably resolved this already.